# Ошибка "TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'."

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Почему возникает ошибка?

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'."

```js
created() {
  window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(() => this.scrollTo(location.hash.slice(1)), 1));
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetTimeOut нужно обвернуть в функцию, и тогда ошибка исчезнет

```
    const scrollTo=this.scrollTo.bind(this)
window.addEventListener("load", () => setTimeout(function(){
  scrollTo()
}, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам прям так в ошибке говорится, "parameter 2 is not of type 'Object" проверьте тип ваших аргументов или их порядок.

Comment: Код сам работает, ошибка в консоли, в этом проблема. Я мог и в переводчике написать, он мне такой же ответ дал бы как ты.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что у тебя не работает - просто ошибка волнует, или код не работает?

Comment: в консоли сообщение, а сам код работает

Comment: Нуу, на вопрос почему я могу ответить - второй параметр неправельного типа, что похоже, не критично, а вот на вопрос как это исправить, ответить не могу.

Comment: setTimeout() является объектом, обвернул  setTimeout() в функцию, и все заработало